# prolog - DCG transformation

Tags: prolog, dcg

What does `E -> T` mean ? Variable `E` implies variable `T` ?

This the code which is linked :

```
e(TS,R) :- t(TS,R).
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say, *This the code which is linked*. What does "linked" mean here? `(->)/2` in the term `E -> T` doesn't exactly mean "implies" but it does have a specific behavior in Prolog depending upon the result of `E` and `T`. `E -> T` fails if `E` fails. `E -> T` fails and doesn't backtrack to `E` if `E` succeeds and then `T` fails (as opposed to `E, T` in which case if `E` succeeds and then `T` fails, it will backtrack to `E`). `E -> T` succeeds if `E` and then `T` succeed. `E -> T` behaves like `E, !, T`.

Comment: Did you really mean `e --> t`? And be mindful of case. It matters in Prolog. And there's a huge difference between `-->` and `->`.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you asking about `E -> T` (if `E` then `T`) and not about `e --> t` (lower case (thanks lurker!) and DCG syntax, where "DCG" is for "Definite Clause Grammar")?

Because the DCG syntax

```
e --> t.
```

is an alias (or a shortcut or syntactic sugar, if you prefer) for

```
e(L1, L2) :- t(L1, L2).
```

More generally speaking, the DCG syntax adds a couple of arguments, at the end of the clauses involved, making a chain on the right side of the `:-` operator where the the start and the end of the chain are the arguments added on the left side.

So (by example)

```
d --> c1, c2, ...., cn.
```

is an alias for

```
d(L1, Lnp1) :- c1(L1, L2), c2(L2, L3), ..., cn(Ln, Lnp1).
```

Comment: @lurker - D'oh! Lower case, your right. Answer corrected; thanks.